# Is there any European country where vehicles are driven on the left of the road?

Tags: europe, driving, factoids

In India, vehicles are right-hand drive (that is, the driver seat is on the right side of vehicle) and the vehicle should be driven on left side of the road.

Is there any European country that follows the same driving style?

Comment: -1 for zero own research effort displayed.

Comment: Not for [much longer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit) :-)

Comment: @Mawg the question concerns [European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe) countries, not [European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union) countries.  (Also, Ireland will remain in the EU and will no doubt continue to drive on the left side of the road.)

Comment: Have patience. Just give it a few hundred million years

Answer (score 21):

According to [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_with_left-hand_traffic#In_Europe), the following European countries have left-hand traffic:

- Cyprus
- Guernsey (Crown dependency of the United Kingdom)
- Ireland
- Isle of Man (Crown dependency of the United Kingdom)
- Jersey (Crown dependency of the United Kingdom)
- Malta
- United Kingdom

Comment: Sweden also had left-hand traffic until 3 September 1967, when everyone switched to the other side of the road: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagen_H

Comment: @mfripp Many other countries did. Czechia switched on the day of German occupation in 1939. (It was scheduled to some later date.)

Comment: An addition to this answer: no for mainland Europe, as all the mentioned territories are island (which had much less of a reason to align with neighboring countries)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, United Kingdom :)

This was pretty straight forward, isn't it?

The long answer is : UK, Ireland, Malta and Cyprus.

Source :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_with_left-hand_traffic

Comment: +1.      Only UK? Remaining all are LHD?

Comment: The others have shared borders - border crossings would be MUCH more interesting if they didn't all drive on the same side...

Comment: @BrianDrummond which shared borders does Eire have with LHD countries?

Comment: @MD-Tech That's probably why Ireland's on the list along with the UK.

Comment: @MD-Tech - Eire shares a border with Northern Ireland, which I part of the UK.